# sort list of matrices by number of columns in R

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I have a list of matrices generated using expand.grid().

```
myarray=matrix(rexp(200),10,3)
list.of.matrices <- apply(expand.grid(rep(list(c(FALSE, TRUE)), ncol(myarray))),
                              1, function(j)myarray[, j, drop = FALSE])
```

When I used the command

```
myarray.dim=sapply(myarray, ncol)
```

I've noticed that the list is not generated in the order that I need. I would like to get them ordered starting from 1 column to 3 if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
lapply(order(sapply(list.of.matrices,ncol)),function(i) list.of.matrices[[i]])
```

Your list has a zero column entry.

Comment: That's great it's exactly what I needed. Do you know why this zero column entry is generated?

Comment: @user1228124 Look at the output of `expand.grid(rep(list(c(FALSE, TRUE)), ncol(myarray)))`.

Comment: or just `list.of.mat[order(sapply(list.of.mat,ncol))]`